# How to pass properties between projects in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

This is a simplified version of my large application, separated into multiple projects which seems very logical to me. I've also tried to incorporate some of the principles of MVVM, although I'm would like to avoid getting too stuck in the weeds with code-heavy stuff like Prism, eventaggregators, etc.

The way the app works is, you select a cat from the list, and the number in the textbox is automatically added to the age of the selected cat. And when the number in the textbox is changed, that number is also added to the age of the selected cat:

[Application Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUNEO.png)

Here is how the solution is organized:

[Code Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcmg.png)

The CatsView and ComputeView user controls are added in the MainView and set to their respective view models. The CatsViewModel contains the SelectedCat property, and when the value changes, it should run the Calculate method in the ComputeViewModel. The ComputeViewModel contains the YearsToAdd property which the textbox is bound to, and when it changes, the Calculate method is also called.

The problem areas are highlighted in red. The first problem is that the CatsViewModel does not have a reference to the ComputeViewModel, and thus cannot call the Calculate method from there. The other problem is that the ComputeViewModel does not know what the selected cat is.

I guess maybe the SelectedCat property could be global, but that is frowned upon. Another solution could be to pass the MainViewModel into the child view models, but that won't work unless I add a reference to the Main project, but that's impossible because it would cause circular dependencies.

What is the solution to this conundrum?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to help you. You should however avoid to have controls that have their own, private view model instances. Such view models are disconnected from the view model structure of your application and hence useless.

Comment: Those you called "code-heavy stuff like Prism, eventaggregators" makes your life easier with this kind of situations. When your project scales larger your need those kind of stuff will enlarge also. What you need is cross component communication. You can achieve create a shared singleton service with observable properties and update from a component and listen from the other one.

Comment: Computeviewmodel sounds rather more like a model class to me. Why aren't you doing calculations as soon as the user commits a change and calling code to do them from the viewmodel for a cat? Which then knows what cat is involved.

Answer (score -1):

With a project your size, I would put all the user interface stuff (this also means the view models) in the *Main Project* (which will then be  WinForms/WPF/UWP application). I will refer to this as the **User Interface**. Your other projects will be class libraries, with no GUI stuff at all.

The **User Interface** will then need a reference to both your class libraries (it will be dependant on them), but the other projects will not know of the user interface (so they will not depend on anything).

When needed, the view models will be able to call methods from your class libraries, but it is important to state that the methods called (in the class libraries) are strictly non-GUI related.

Comment: Thank you @Noceo, I will take this into consideration. The thinking behind the way I organized the solution was to separate it into functional areas, pretending that each project was done by a different person. This way, every project would contain everything that's related to that project's general sphere of functionality, including both GUI and non-GUI stuff. Still don't know which is the best way.